# Exec At slower than Sql OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server

So I recently found out that you can pass parameters with EXEC AT in SQL to a linked server like Oracle.

I grabbed a query and tested out first without parameters

```
EXEC ('SELECT RD6001 as Referencia,
              RD6002 as UAP,
              RD6030 as QTD_AB_PDP_W01 
              FROM D805DATPOR.TRP060D 
              where RD6001 not like ''%OP%'' 
              and RD6001 not like ''%PT%'' ') 
AT MACPAC
```

however this takes like 45 seconds to get 2k rows....

If I run

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT RD6001 as Referencia,
            RD6002 as UAP,RD6030 as QTD_AB_PDP_W01 
     FROM D805DATPOR.TRP060D 
     where RD6001 not like ''%OP%'' 
     and RD6001 not like ''%PT%'' ')
```

this only takes 2-3 seconds at most, and If I run the EXEC AT query after this one it takes 1 second. Why is EXEC AT speed different in the beginning?

Comment: Most likely because the SQL Plan Cache didn't have that query the 1st time it ran. Then you ran it 2 more times and since it was in the plan cache after the 1st run, it ran faster.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that Openquery executes always faster the first time though since both execute the query in the remote server